# changing static variables from another method in java

Tags: java, static-methods

I want to create a method, `moveQ()`, that I will be able to call in method `find()` in order to change `find()`'s variables, but in method `moveQ()` I am getting the error `cannot find symbol variable x` in this example `x`, `y`, and `z` are the variables I need to change.

**edited:**

I also have a few restrictions as this is taken from an exercise from Java course:
1. method must be static.
2. global variables are not allowed.
3. time complexity should be less than O(n), I cannot add to memory complexity (meaning can not use another array or objects). 
4. the method find() can not accept parameters.

In the actual program, I need to write a static boolean method that will return true if number `x` is found in an array that is divided into quadrants. To do that, it searches for each quadrant's highest number. If `x` is larger than the quadrant highest number, then I need to move to the next quadrant.

`x`, `y`, and `z` are the maximum number, middle number and the minimum number of the quadrant of the array and by changing them, I can move quadrants.

I've already written the `find()` method, but I want to use helper methods to make the code better.

Is what I am trying to do even possible, and if so how do I accomplish it?

```
public class Test
{
    public static boolean find()
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        int z = 30;
        change(x,y,z); // call helper method to change this method's variables.
        System.out.println(x); // should be 20
        System.out.println(y); // should be 22
        System.out.println(z); // should be 15
    }

    //helper method to be called from find() method
    private static void change(int changeX ,int changeY,int changeZ)
    {
        //change find() variables.
        x = changeX * 2; 
        y = changeY + 2;
        z = changeZ /2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your second method. You pass changeX, changeY, and changeZ but try to set the values of x, y, and z. The variables x, y, and z are not within the scope of this method and therefore the program will throw an error.

Moreover, this methodology will not work regardless of these names. Java does not allow you to change the values of primitives when you pass them to a new method. The best solution is probably to put them in an array and change the second method to accept an array. The body of your first method may now look like

```
int [] intarray = new int[3];
intarray[0] = 10;
intarray[1] = 20;
intarray[2] = 30;
change(intarray);
System.out.println(intarray[0]);
System.out.println(intarray[1]);
System.out.println(intarray[2]);
```

and the second method would become

```
private static void change(int [] changeArray) {
    changeArray[0] *= 2;
    changeArray[1] += 2;
    changeArray[2] /= 2;
}
```

(The *=, +=, and /= operators are shorthand for what you were doing above.

Answer (score 0):

You declared variables inside of method so you don't have access to them, if you want to change them you either make them global(define them outside of method):

```
 public class Test
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
void yourMethod(){

  }
}
```

Or change method find to take x, y and z values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a class encapsulating your `x`, `y`, `z` as fields and convert your methods to its instance methods (that is, they should not be static anymore).

```
public class Calculation {
    private int x = 10, y = 20, z = 30;

    public boolean find()
    {
        x = 10;
        y = 20;
        z = 30;
        change(x,y,z); // call helper method to change this method's variables.
        System.out.println(x); // should be 20
        System.out.println(y); // should be 22
        System.out.println(z); // should be 15
    }

    private void change(int changeX ,int changeY,int changeZ)
```

and so on.

Then create an instance of it and call your methods on it:

```
Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
calculation.find();
...
```

Comment: thank you all for you'r help, by you'r answers I understand that what I am trying to do with the restrictions I have in the exercise (I edited my original massage and added the restrictions) is not possible.

Comment: Good suggestion! nearly same as my answer.

but sadly it's not suitable now he changed his problem specifications and put restrictions on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in more organized way :

Create `Calculation` class then put all your variables and methods on it

File **Calculation.java**:

```
public class Calculation {

    private int x = 10;
    private int y = 20;
    private int z = 30;

    public void setX(int value){
        x = value;
    }
    public void setY(int value){
        y = value;
    }
    public void setZ(int value){
        z = value;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public int getZ(){
        return z;
    }

    private void change(int changeX, int changeY, int changeZ){
        setX(changeX * 2);
        setY(changeY + 2);
        setZ(changeZ / 2);
    }

    public void find(){
        change(x,y,z);
        System.out.println(getX()); 
        System.out.println(getY()); 
        System.out.println(getZ());
    }
}
```

After that just create new object of class `Calculation` in your main program and call `find()` method on this object variable

File **Main.java**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculation c = new Calculation();
        c.find();
    }   
}
```

**Output**:

```
20
22
15
```

Comment: @Tsvi Moshkovitz Check this solution it's better organized than your code.

Comment: great method, but it because of the restrictions in the exercise I cannot write it like that.

Comment: No problem but you update your question late and I didn't see any of the restrictions.

you should be more clear and precise when you ask for specific solution to your problem.